# Google Maps Places API issue with getPlaces() function

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Can someone tell me why the getPlaces() function returns a space character string below?

In head element I have the link to the Google maps script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3.exp&key=MyKey&libraries=places"></script>
```

Javascript code:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    streetViewControl: false
  });
  var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.7033177, -93.0573533),
    new google.maps.LatLng(41, -93)
  );

  map.fitBounds(defaultBounds);

  var input = document.getElementById('addressSearch');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  var markers = [];

  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }

    markers = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
      var place = places[i];
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location,
        draggable: true
      });
      markers.push(marker);

      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    if (markers.length == 1) map.setZoom(17);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
  });
});
```

This code is taken from Google's developer site, from the example with the text search field, so it should work fine. 2 days ago, it worked fine. Now it doesn't. The problem is that the `getPlaces()` method returns a string with a space character and not an array as it should. What am I missing here?

**Update:** Ok, my question was not clear enough. What does work is the autocomplete functionality in the search box. What does not work is the `places_changed` event and specifically the line

```
var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
```

The `places` variable should contain an array, so that in the next `for` loop, it will create an array of markers and put them on the map. Instead, what it returns is an empty string.

Comment: Entering "Liberty Station, Historic Decatur Road, San Diego, CA" on the [Google example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) returns 2 places for me.  Do you have an example of what doesn't work (or a live example that shows the problem or a jsfiddle)?

Comment: Where in the documentation did you see a google.maps.places.SearchBox() constructor?

Comment: That was my question as well, but it is in the example (link in my previous comment), just not in the Places library documentation (which of course makes it dangerous, as undocumented things can and do change...)

Comment: Aha! The Google example loads v=3.exp (experimental), as you said "dangerous".

Comment: @Marcelo, the link for the SearchBox example used in Google is at https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

Comment: Yes, I've seen it, but it is undocumented because it's part of the **experimental** version. You should never use the **experimental** version unless you know very well what you're doing. See my answer below!

Comment: There is no getPlaces() method in the documentation. Only getPlace().

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of:

```
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
```

try:

```
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
```

and instead of

```
var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
```

try

```
var place = searchBox.getPlace();
```

Comment: Point taken. I should never use the unstable version. The code worked perfectly a few days ago, I suspect Google changed something in the mean time. I will switch to Autocomplete, I already tested it and it works. Thanks for the responses guys.